Iterate over values in BigQuery - similar to iterating over key-value pairs in a dictionary
Seeking some help with a BQ query. I'm new to BigQuery and SQL, so please be gentle ;).
I have a BQ table with 10 rows and 2 columns. My intention is to run another BQ query, iterating over the cell values. And create a new table for each iteration.
I'm imagining this to be similar to running a for loop in Python, iterating over key, value pair of a dictionary.
Table I have:
example_table:



Column A
Column B




val_1a
val_1b


val_2a
val_2b



What I want to do:
for col1_cell, col2_cell in example_table:
  bq query

I tried the FOR IN procedure, as described here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#iterate
FOR value IN (
  SELECT val1, val2
  FROM `my_dataset.example_table`
)
DO
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `my_dataset.new_table`
AS(
  SELECT
  <<My query here>>
);
END FOR;

This creates the new_table, but values get overwritten, with only 1 table being created.
When I try to declare a variable, I get either "Expected end of input but got keyword FOR" or "Variable declarations are allowed only at the start of a block or script " error
DECLARE my_array ARRAY<STRUCT<val1 STRING, val2 STRING>>;
SET my_project_service = (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(col1, col2))
  FROM `from_my_dataset.my_table`
);

FOR my_array IN (
  SELECT val1, val2
  FROM `my_dataset.example_table`
)
DO
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `my_dataset.new_table`
AS(
  SELECT
  <<My query here>>
);
END FOR;

Appreciate any help, thank you.

The idea behind SQL is to process all rows parallel. Therefore looping over rows is not the intended usage. In case values from previous or following rows are needed for calculations, there are window functions. Please provide the goal of your for loop. Insert adds new rows to a table.

Thanks @Samuel. I will look into the Window function. My for loop is intended to take 2 values, then run another query and create a new table. Do this for all 10 rows, so will have 10 new tables at the end of the for loop.

If in each loop another table (different table name) shall be created, the Create table statement needs to be created by execute immediate given the SQL query as a string.

As a commenter mentioned, this is possible in BigQuery; you can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to run SQL commands that you've preconstructed as a string.
Here is a minimal example of how to do something like what you're trying to accomplish:
FOR value IN (
  SELECT a, b
  FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS a, 2 AS b
  )
)
DO EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
SELECT """
|| CAST(value.a AS STRING)
|| """ AS x
""";
END FOR;

The results of running this in the BigQuery UI look like this:

Wait, what!?
Three queries occur:

first we SELECT the table with columns a and b
we loop through the rows of this table procedurally; each row gets referred to as value in the context of the loop and contains fields a and b
there are two rows, so the loop runs twice
each time it runs we DO something. What we do is EXECUTE IMMEDIATE some SQL, i.e. run a SQL query
hence, three SQL queries run

What is the nature of these looped-over queries?
Using the string concatenation operator || and the multiline string syntax """, we stick together three different bits:

SELECT 
value.a, typecast to a string (this is "1" on the first loop, "3" on the second loop)
 AS x

So in the first loop the query will be created as follows: SELECT 1 AS x
(just about the simplest query you can run in BigQuery; it returns a single row containing the value 1 in a single column called x)
... and in the second loop we'll instead execute SELECT 3 AS x.
Adapting This
In your case, you could replace SELECT with CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE and use your actual query to define the table.
Should You Do This?
My gut says 'No'.
Sometimes you will have some constraints that mean you have to do everything in BigQuery; for those cases this is a very powerful set of features.
Most of the time, though, it is better to use scripting languages (you mentioned Python yourself) to instruct BigQuery to run a set of queries. I would recommend using google-cloud-bigquery, the official Python Client library, if you are able.

Thank you, for your detailed response. I ended up using the Python client for BQ and was able to achieve the end result - so much better than direct BQ queries. Thanks again!
